# redirect page delay or go on

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page with links to other sites. When a user clicks a link it goes through redirect.php which redirects it to the desired site.

What I want to gain is this:
in the redirect page I put:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=<?php echo $post_url ?>" />
```

in order to make the user stay in the redirect.php for 3 secs. I want to let the user two options in this page:

1. To hold on and freeze redirect.php if it wants to read the displayed content in it.
2. To skip it instantly or after reading the content, and go to the desired site.

I prefer PHP but I believe it takes jquery and I wonder if someone can redirect me (funny me) to a working example with free code whether jquery, JS or PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: OK, that's good for the case of a user that wants to go through instantly or after reading the content, but how do I so called freeze the meta refresh counter if the user wants to stay?

Comment: Sorry, my comment was premature. I deleted it as quickly as I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `<meta http-equiv="refresh"... >` use a Javascript redirect, with jQuery it might look like this:

```
$(function(){
    window.redirectTimeout = setTimeout(function(){  // set a redirect timeout of 3 seconds
        window.location.href = '<?php echo $post_url ?>';
    }, 3000);

    $('#cancelBtn').on('click', function(){  // assuming #cancelBtn is used to cancel redirection 
        clearTimeout(window.redirectTimeout);
    });
});
```

To go directly to the other site just use a simple link in your page:

```
<a href="<?php echo $post_url ?>">Go there now!</a>
```

Comment: @ofermc Ein beaya :). Consider using `.load()` instead of `.ready()` as Roamer-1888 suggested.

Comment: Hey Yotam, back again... I want this page to be skipped on back pressed. I've replaced window.location.href = '<?php echo $post_url ?>'; with window.location.replace('<?php echo $post_url ?>'); but the page still loads when the user presses back on browser from the page it was redirected to. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: hey @ofermc, sorry for not being here for the month. Did you get this solved? what do you mean by skipped? I'm afraid that if you want is to go "double back" this is not possible in any conventional way, you can maybe try using php's $_SESSION to store the previous page then on second load redirect to the previous page instead..

Comment: Hey Yotam, thanks for you caring. I finally managed to get it right with the assistance of Roamer-1888 in the accepted answer below. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First get rid of the meta refresh - it's not cancelable.

Then...

**HTML**

```
<a id="go" href="http://.....">Go</a>
<a id="hold">Hold</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    //javascript equivalent of meta refresh
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        $("#go").click();
    }, 3000);

    //cancel the timeout if hold button is clicked
    $("#hold").on('click', function() {
        clearTimeout(t);
    });
});
```

It's better to do everything in response to the window's onload event in this case as it will give the user a better chance to read the content before the redirect fires. The document's ready event fires earlier - before all the content has loaded.

Plus, with this solution, the redirect url is defined once, not twice.

Comment: Thanks. I accept what you're saying and will use it. However ' $("#go").click();' means that counter will fire only when clicking "#go" and I want it to be fired right as the document finished uploading, so this part might suit other cases, but not mine. Thank you!

Comment: No, you are misreading the code. `$("#go").click();` triggers an artificial click on the Go link. That way, the redirect url only needs to be defined once - as the Go link's href.